# Sharing Variable Between Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

I am a Ruby/Rails newbie and am having difficulty passing a variable between two of my methods. In this scenario I am playing around with an authorize method and a new method that creates a new folder on Google Drive. When I have it all together in one method it works fine but when I separate them I receive this error "NoMethodError in EssaysController#new
undefined method `create_file' for nil:NilClass". I tried making drive an instance variable as shown below but still have no luck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
def authorize
  # Loads client secrets
  client_id = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load

  # Assign it to authorization
  authorization = client_id.to_authorization

  # Create new Drive instance
  @drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new

  @drive.authorization = authorization

  auth_client = authorization.dup

  auth_client.update!(
    :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    :approval_prompt => "force",
    :grant_type => "refresh_token"
  )
  auth_client.fetch_access_token!
end

def new
  file_metadata = {
    name: 'Hello World',
    mime_type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
  }
  file = @drive.create_file(file_metadata, fields: 'id')
  puts "Folder Id: #{file.id}"
end
```

Comment: @drive is not initialized. you have to initialize method before using it.

Comment: Would the initialization take place before `def authorize`? Thanks!

Comment: @drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new needs to happen before @drive.create_file(file_metadata, fields: 'id').

Comment: That definitely seems better! I received an authorization error so had to also move client_id to def initialize as well. In this case, should I even bother with def authorize? For some reason I am also losing my styles.

Comment: Turns out I had to call `super` in initialize. Seems to be good now! Now I just have to think whether or not I still need def authorize. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Better yet... If I put in `before_filter :authorize` then make drive an instance variable I don't even need `def initialize`.